# How to get extended locale information by api

Tags: c, linux, locale, strftime

I want to getinformation about the current locale.
The only interface I could find is:

```
locale.h: extern struct lconv *localeconv (void);
```

But the `struct lconv` only contains numeric and financial locale information. I also want to get the time related information that's used by strftime. In particular the names of days and date format.

Tracing `locale abday` I found `"/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive"` but I cannot find any information about its format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`nl_langinfo(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nl_langinfo.3.html). From the [glibc docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Information.html):

> #### 7.7 Accessing Locale Information
>
> …  To do this the C
> library provides two functions: **localeconv** and **nl_langinfo**. The former
> is part of ISO C and therefore portable, but has a brain-damaged
> interface. The second is part of the Unix interface and is portable in
> as far as the system follows the Unix standards.
>
> • [The Lame Way to Locale Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/The-Lame-Way-to-Locale-Data.html#The-Lame-Way-to-Locale-Data):       ISO C’s localeconv.
>
> • [The Elegant and Fast Way](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/The-Elegant-and-Fast-Way.html#The-Elegant-and-Fast-Way):      X/Open’s nl_langinfo.